# JavaFx 2.x: Rectangle custom property on lower right corner

Tags: properties, javafx, shapes

Is it possible in Rectangle class  to create a doubleproperty similar to
DoubleProperty xProperty() upper-left corner but that defines the X coordinates of the lower-right corner?

Same problem for Y coordinate.

These new properties should be able to be passed as parameter to method bindDirectional.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, which should solve this problem.

```
DoubleBinding maxX = rectangle.xProperty().add(rectangle.widthProperty());
DoubleBinding maxY = rectangle.yProperty().add(rectangle.heightProperty());

otherProperty.bind(maxX);
anotherProperty.bind(maxY);
```

However because these properties are computed, you can't use them in bindBidirectional. The reason being that if `otherProperty` sets a different value for `maxX` `JavaFX` can't work out which of `xProperty` and `widthProperty` to change. You'll need to create your own property for doing that, depending on how you want changes from `otherProperty` to affect `xProperty` and `widthProperty`.